# how can i load a weight file with n classes in a CNN model with n+1 classes

Tags: python, keras

I have built a CNN model with 3 class labels and also have generated the weight (.h5 file) for it. I want to use that weight file with the same model , but the only difference is that it has now 4 classes instead of 3.

I tried using

```
checkpoint = model.load_weights("filename.h5")
```

but i always get the error as class mismatch.

can anyone help me with any kind of suggestion

Comment: How you created model, `Sequential model API` or with `functional API`?

Comment: Sequential model API

Answer (score 0):

Maybe follow yanboliang advice in [Keras: removing layers with model.layers.pop() doesn't work](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22479), by overwriting the last layer of the model with a new layer of 4 class outputs?

Comment: I tried posting it as answer but for some reason i couldn't. so i am posting it as comment hoping it might help someone.
since "model.layers.pop()" was not working for me, all I did is call the old model, added old model to the new model and then added the Dense layer. 

Here is the code to do that:

    prev_model = load_model("model name")

    prev_model.summary()
    
    new_model = Sequential()
    new_model.add(prev_model)
    new_model.add(Dense(1024))
    new_model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
    new_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    new_model.add(Dense(4,activation='softmax'))